# What's the most accurate way to determine user geolocation in the browser?

Tags: geolocation, location, geoip

I found a few examples suggesting Google AJAX APIs.

This link typifies the advice I have found so far: http://briancray.com/2009/05/29/find-web-visitors-location-javascript-google-api/

However, the location is often wrong with the Google APIs.

Other sites seem to know exactly which city I'm in, though, without me entering any information.

Suggestions?  Is there something cross-browser (ignoring IE6) and reliable?

Comment: How accurate do you need the location to be, and how important is the accuracy? For instance, a web-based 911 system wants to be able to send help to the right house. A system to target advertisements need only hit the right neighborhood.

Comment: Hi John, the right neighborhood is more than accurate enough.  Really, we just need the right city.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was going to answer with a few points but sometimes referencing a decent article is the way to go. I recently came across this Smashing Magazine article by Christian Heilmann which explains the issues, solutions and further info on all things GeoLocational.

[Entering the wonderful world of Geolocation](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/03/08/entering-the-wonderful-world-of-geo-location/)

Answer (score 1):

check http://hostip.info
it is an opensource database.

Comment: Well, I jut gave it a spin over some italian addresses and it didn't  really cut it. One in **Milan** was mapped over **Rome**. One in **Sardinia** was generically mapped over **Italy**. And with **my** address... it **couldn't even figure** i'm in Italy at all. Maybe it's good on North-America, dunno.

Answer (score 0):

Other that the **costly GeoIP database** and the **limited js api**, (cited in the [smash](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/03/08/entering-the-wonderful-world-of-geo-location/) article Brian linked) [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/) also offers a number of free **Geolite DBs**, for download.

http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity

They are redistributable under [this license](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/LICENSE.txt).

Answer (score 0):

Try [Webshims geolocation module](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/demos/geolocation.html) it implements navigator.geolocation API if browser doesn't support it.